# Is there a way to check if a url has route constraint in Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a page with route constraint `@page "/users/{userId:int}"`

I have another page `@page "/users/"`

I want to know which of the url is being routed to, then perform an action based on that.

I'm thinking if I should get a way to check if a url has route constraint (and even get the constraint and its type), my problem would be solved.

**MORE INFO**

I'm checking this on a nav menu page so I could know which menu item to set as active

Comment: Where are you trying to perform this test? Why?

Comment: I have a nav menu page where I need to check this so I could know which menu item to retain

Comment: Shouldn't that just be some kind of `if (userId.HasValue){ <a asp-route-userId="@userId" .... } else { ... }`

Comment: where would I get the `userId` from on the nav menu page?

Comment: From `.Context` / `.ViewBag` or from it's model? Or are you wanting to pick it up from an "ambient route value" based on the current request?

Comment: actually, my initial thought was getting it somewhere in the NavigationManager class.

Comment: If this is related to authentication, then can pass AuthenticationState as a cascasding parameter. But your use case is still not very clear to me.

Comment: The Router (usually in the App component) has routedata that you can cascade down and use. That routedata has properties that might be of use. I'm not sure what you mean by "which menu item to retain" - so am not sure if this will be helpful

Comment: @MayurEkbote, my use case is not related to authentication. I have nav menus, users is one of the menu items. I have another page, which displays the user details(which uses user id to route), it is not a nav menu. What I want is whenever I navigate to the user details, I want the user menu retained as the current menu., just like the counter menu is being retained when you're on the counter page in the [blazor official example](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/try)

Comment: Purely from UI perspective? I.e. to show the user menu as active?

Answer (score 0):

in this scenario if you call users page then @page "/users/" this page will be called if you call users with a parameter than @page "users/{userid:int}" will call
its on depend you what is you calling

Comment: I want to programmatically check this after the call.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in a lifecycle event like this:

```
[Parameter]
public int? userId { get; set; }

protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
  if (userId is not null)
  {
    // Perform action when user id is present
  }
}
```

Note that [OnParametersSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle#after-parameters-are-set-onparameterssetasync-1) also have an async version.